# Succinctly adding verbose output to GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to add verbose output to a gnu makefile if `V=1` is passed on the command line.

I can already do it in three lines as follows:

```
ifeq ($(V),1)
$(info SRC_FILES=$(SRC_FILES))
endif
```

Is there some more terse idiom, e.g., that appears all on one line? Ideally I'd like something like:

```
$(verbose SRC_FILES=$(SRC_FILES))
```

which may not be possible, or at least a one-liner like:

```
$(if $(V) $(info SRC_FILES=$(SRC_FILES)))
```

Comment: Have you checked if the available [debug options](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002d_002ddebug) might float your boat?

Comment: @DevSolar - yes, and they don't. I do use those too, but here I need `V` to control makefile specific output as shown above.

Comment: Just to be clear your one-liner above at the end would work if you had the syntax right: there needs to be a comma between the condition and the then-clause not a space...

Comment: @Mad yup that would do it! Good enough for an answer...

Answer (score 1):

`$(info $(if $(V),SRC_FILES=$(SRC_FILES)))` almost does what you want. Its only drawback is that it outputs an empty line when V is undefined.

**EDIT**: from MadScientist's remark, and as initially suggested by BeeOnRope, `$(if $(V),$(info SRC_FILES=$(SRC_FILES)))` works exactly as expected, without the empty line when V is undefined.

You could also define a macro that prints an info message about a variable if and only if `V` is defined:

```
define verbose
$(if $(V),$(info $(1) = $($(1))))
endef

$(call verbose,SRC_FILES)
```

Of course, if you want a more generic macro, you can pass it the text to print:

```
define verbose
$(if $(V),$(info $(1)))
endef

$(call verbose,SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES))
```

Note that there are other types of information that you may want to control with a verbosity level variable. For the commands echoing, the commands outputs and the *quiet* command options I frequently use the following:

```
# Verbosity
ifeq ($(V),)
Q     := @
MQ    := --quiet
ECHO  := echo
OUT   := &> /dev/null
else ifeq ($(V),1)
Q     :=
MQ    :=
ECHO  := echo
OUT   :=
else
$(error V: invalid value ($(V)))
endif

foo:
    $(Q)$(ECHO) 'making $@' && \
    some-command $@ $(OUT)

bar: cuz
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(MQ) $@

...
```

Comment: Why not `$(if $(V),$(info ....))`?  That won't generate an empty line if false...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be practical:

```
verbose = $(if $(VERBOSITY),$(info $(-verbose)))
-verbose = $(if $(findstring 0,$(VERBOSITY)),$1 )$(if $(findstring 1,$(VERBOSITY)),$2 )$(if $(findstring 2,$(VERBOSITY)),$3 )$(if $(findstring 3,$(VERBOSITY)),$4 )$(if $(findstring 4,$(VERBOSITY)),$5 )$(if $(findstring 5,$(VERBOSITY)),$6 )$(if $(findstring 6,$(VERBOSITY)),$7 )$(if $(findstring 7,$(VERBOSITY)),$8 )$(if $(findstring 8,$(VERBOSITY)),$9 )$(if $(findstring 9,$(VERBOSITY)),$(10) )

VERBOSITY = 0

$(call verbose,warninglevel 1,warninglevel 2,warninglevel 3,info 1,info 2,info 3)

VERBOSITY = 2

$(call verbose,warninglevel 1,warninglevel 2,warninglevel 3,info 1,info 2,info 3)


VERBOSITY = 012345

$(call verbose,warninglevel 1,warninglevel 2,warninglevel 3,info 1,info 2,info 3)
```

Output:

```
warninglevel 1
warninglevel 3
warninglevel 1 warninglevel 2 warninglevel 3 info 1 info 2 info 3
```

I have added it to [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt).